# Store objects with key-value pairs

Tags: sql, arrays, json, database, database-design

I have the following data, (All the data will be **TEXT**).

The following data is for Language files for multi-language translation.

```
data: {
 'MAIN_KEY':{
    'A_UNIQUE_KEY':'data1',
    'A_UNIQUE_KEY':'data2',
    'A_UNIQUE_KEY':'data3',
  },
 'MAIN_KEY':{
    'A_UNIQUE_KEY':'data1',
    'A_UNIQUE_KEY':'data2',
    'A_UNIQUE_KEY':'data3',
    'A_UNIQUE_KEY':'data2',
    'A_UNIQUE_KEY':'data3',
  },
  ......
}
```

Here, the **MAIN_KEY** will be different for each set. In this case component name, Eg: **LOGIN_PAGE**

**A_UNIQUE_KEY** will also different in each case. In this case field name. Eg: **USER_NAME** and so on.

**The number of **Key-value** pairs in each set will also be different.**

I need to store the data for multiple languages. But the **MAIN_KEY** and **A_UNIQUE_KEY** will be the same for every file.

Every file will be of the same structure but only the **data1**, **data2**.. will be different,

What I want to achieve is that to store and manage the data in this format and later generate a JSON file through an API for my different applications. I should be able to do `CRUD` operations on this data.

Is creating a Database is the only option here?

Comment: Now: Please ask exactly 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. But--There's no such thing as "best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design & all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), ask 1 question. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Comment: @philipxy I understand.

Answer (score 2):

XML and JSON are hierarchical structures like a tree, where a parent node can have child nodes and each child node has exactly one parent node, whereas a database is typically a relational system where an entity can have many parents, siblings and children so-to-say :-)

This means in order to store your JSON you have at least these three options:

1. Create a simple database in an RDBMS where each child table has just one parent table.
2. Have just one table in an RDBMS and store your JSON in a row in that table. (After all the JSON is just a string.)
3. Use a non-relational DBMS. There even exist JSON DBMS, if I'm not mistaken.

Which option you choose would depend on your data and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have updated the question with little more info

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using **DynamoDB**.

With DynamoDB I can store the data in **One Table** using the **Composite Key**. And use **DynamoDBMapper** to do the CRUD operations.